# postmessage to a process

Tags: c#, key, postmessage

I have a problem with posting a message to a process. When I send a key like `A` it is working great, but when I am sending a "special character" like `Enter` or `F3` it is not working.

Here is my code :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

public IntPtr SendKeystroke(IntPtr hWnd, Keys k)
{
     return PostMessage(hWnd, 0x100, (IntPtr)k, (IntPtr)0);
}
```

And here is executing a method :

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("name")[0];
SendKeystroke(p.Handle, Keys.A);
SendKeystroke(p.Handle, Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: What is the return value of the failed `SendKeyStroke` call?

Comment: When i am doing
`IntPtr x = m_input.SendKeystroke(p.Handle, Keys.Enter);
textBox1.Text = x.ToString();`

it prints "1"